# Lisp code debugging

Tags: debugging, clojure, lisp

[During web searching](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/081023.html), I found the following comment : Traditional Lisp debugging practices can still be used.

- What are the traditional debugging practices?
- Normally, what tools are used for debugging lisp (with/without emacs)?

Comment: @rlb.usa I dont know what constitues a "toy language", but Lisp has been used in several logistics planning systems by the US Army, been deployed to spacecraft control (and even remotely debugged), in several AI and AI-related systems, and behind ITA Software, the search enginge for cheap flights, just bought by google for $700M.

Comment: SLIME is an __awesome__ development environment for CL that runs on Emacs. I never use any other REPL for CL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what Bill meant specifically, but IME:

Typically your editor will have a running instance connected to it.  You can compile functions immediately to insert them into the running image -- since Lisp has its own compiler, you're just telling the running image to read and compile a small section of text.  Or you can run functions directly, to see what they do.

When an exception is thrown (or a condition is signaled, if you're lucky enough to be in a dialect with conditions), the debugger will show you the stack trace and let you decide how to continue.

The major difference between Lisp and other high-level compiled languages is that in Lisp you're basically always writing code with the debugger attached.

Answer (score 3):

As clojure was tagged in the question, I'll give our perspective.

Class files generated by the clojure compiler include line- and method-based debugging info, so any java debugger will interoperate directly with clojure code, including breakpoints and object inspection.

If you use emacs/slime as your development environment, integration with slime's debugger has recently been included. As documentation is a little sparse, it's probably best to check out the scope of the support on github directly.

Answer (score 2):

Run edebug-defun in emacs and you will see that lisp is magic.

Answer (score 2):

In something that I would call approaches a "traditional set of Lisp debugging techniques" are:

- Debug printouts
- Function tracing (each invocation of a traced function
  is printed with an indentation that corresponds to call depth, on return the return
  value is printed).
- Explicit invocation of the in-image debugger
- Ending up in the in-image debugger due to a bug (trying to add an integer and a symbol, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Basically just things like adding code to print out values as it runs so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Sounds lika a C# programmer.. (it's a compliment)